# How to find which value is closest to a number in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, comparison

I have the following code in C:

```
#define CONST 1200
int a = 900;
int b = 1050;
int c = 1400;

if (A_CLOSEST_TO_CONST) {
  // do something
}
```

What is a convenient way to check whether if a is the closest value to CONST among a,b and c ?

**Edit:**

It doesn't matter if I have 3 variables or an array like this (it could be more than 3 elements):

```
int values[3] = {900, 1050, 1400};
```

Comment: it's a search exercise.  Generally min (abs(val-CONST))

Comment: It is more a math problem than a C coding issue. Try to minimize the absolute value of the difference between your CONST and your number.

Comment: I don't want the closest value, I want to know if a particular chosen variable (say, a) is the closest

Comment: @pinouchon In the second line compare your a to result of your search (for better results cache the result of your search)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for three variables:

```
if (abs(a - CONST) <= abs(b - CONST) && abs(a - CONST) <= abs(c - CONST)) {
    // a is the closest
}
```

This works with an array of one or more elements, where n is the number of elements:

```
int is_first_closest(int values[], int n) {
    int dist = abs(values[0] - CONST);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (abs(values[i] - CONST) < dist) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/8ip4L#view_edit_box)

Comment: This is the idea. I was wondering if you can easily generalize it. (to 4 variables for example)

Comment: @pinouchon: It would be a whole lot nicer if you used an array of n elements instead of n variables.

Comment: If you want to use this linear approach, insert the constants into an array and loop trough it, comparing each element.

Comment: @markByers Edited my question, I would be glad if you have a generic solution with an array

Comment: One way to make this function more generic would be to pass a third parameter representing the position of the integer we're curious about. If you wanted to keep the logic in is_first_closest() the same, simply swap the first value with the value of the desired position at the beginning then back before returning.

Answer (score 3):

Compare the absolute value of (a-CONST), (b-CONST) and (c-CONST). Whichever absolute value is lowest, that one is closest.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generalized method. The `min_element()` function takes an int array, array size, and pointer to a comparison function. The comparison predicate returns *true* if the first values is *less than* the second value. A function that just returned `a < b` would find the smallest element in the array. The `pinouchon()` comparison predicate performs your *closeness* comparison.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONST 1200

int pinouchon(int a, int b)
{
    return abs(a - CONST) < abs(b - CONST);
}

int min_element(const int *arr, int size, int(*pred)(int, int))
{
    int i, found = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (pred(arr[i], found)) found = arr[i];
    }
    return found;
}

int main()
{
    int values[3] = {900, 1050, 1400};
    printf("%d\n", min_element(values, 3, pinouchon));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I m adding something in Mark Byres code.....

```
int is_first_closest(int values[]) {
    int dist = abs(values[0] - CONST),closest;     //calculaing first difference
    int size = sizeof( values )                    //calculating the size of array
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (abs(values[i] - CONST) < dist) {       //checking for closest value
             dist=abs(values[i] - CONST);          //saving closest value in dist
             closest=i;                            //saving the position of the closest value
        }
    }
    return values[i];
}
```

This function will take an array of integers and return the number which is closest to the CONST.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare your constant to every element. (works well for 3 elements but it's a very bad solution for bigger elementcount, in which case i suggest using some sort of divide and conquer method). After you compare it, take their differences, the lowest difference is the one that the const is closest to)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a reaction to your edit of the original question and your comment.
(Notice that to determine the end of array we could use different approaches, the one i shall use in this particular scenario is the simplest one.)

```
// I think you need to include math.h for abs() or just implement it yourself.
// The code doesn't deal with duplicates.
// Haven't tried it so there might be a bug lurking somewhere in it.

const int ArraySize = <your array size>;
const int YourConstant = <your constant>;
int values[ArraySize] = { ... <your numbers> ... };
int tempMinimum = abs(YourArray[0] - YourConstant); // The simplest way
    for (int i = 1; i < ArraySize; i++) { // Begin with iteration i = 1 since you have your 0th difference computed already.
        if (abs(YourArray[i] - YourConstant) < tempMinumum) {
            tempMinumum = abs(YourArray[i] - YourConstant);
        }
    }

// Crude linear approach, not the most efficient.
```

Answer (score 0):

For a large sorted set, you should be able to use a binary search to find the two numbers which (modulo edge cases) border the number, one of those has to be the closest.

So you would be able to achieve O(Log n) performance instead of O(n).

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
closest_value := NULL
closest_distance := MAX_NUMBER
for(value_in_list)              
    distance := abs(value_in_list - CONST)
    if (distance < closest_distance)
        closest_value := value_in_list
        closest_distance := distance
print closest_value, closest_distance
```