# How to pick two numbers based on if their difference is closest to a given number?

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code:

```
float difference = 6.5;
float values[] = {1.3, 7.0, 6.4, 15.1};
float min;
float max;
```

I want to assign `min` and `max` so that their difference `max-min` is closest to `difference`.
In this case, min should be 1.3 and max 7.0.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is values sorted or not?

Comment: Not necessarily. Modified the example to show it.

Comment: Would you not want to wait for [answers to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233951/how-to-find-which-value-is-closest-to-a-number-in-c), implement that and then see what you can come up with for this situation?

Comment: Smells like the [Subset Sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: @Bart I thought that with the answer to the previous question, it would help to solve this one. Now that I have the answer, it turns out that it's not so helpful, and I am still stuck. Put another way: if you have this problem only, asking the [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233951/how-to-find-which-value-is-closest-to-a-number-in-c) is not such a great thing to do.

Comment: it's not 'min' and 'max' though.  This is about picking a pair of numbers whose difference is the closest to the one given.  Right?

Comment: @AustinSalonen not really, I don't think this is NP since you don't need to check all combinations. Even a brut-force approach would run in n^2

Comment: ` values =` should be `value[] = `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(n) solution, assuming the array is sorted and n is the focal difference:

Start off with two iterators at both ends of the array: `i` and `j`.

**1)** Check differences `j-i`, `(j-1)-i`, `j-(i+1)`.

**2)** If the minimum is `j-i`, you found the answer.

```
Proof: If j-i is closer to n than (j-1)-i, it will be closer to n than (j-k)-i.
```

**3)** If `(j-1)-i` is closest, move iterator `j` to `j-1` go to **1)**.

**4)** If `j-(i+1)` is closest, move iterator `i` to `i+1` go to **1)**.

A run on your example:

```
  i               j
{1.3, 6.4, 7.0, 15.1}

j-i     = 13.8
(j-1)-i = 5.7
j-(i+1) = 8.7
```

Move iterator j one position left:

```
  i         j      
{1.3, 6.4, 7.0, 15.1}

j-i     = 5.7
(j-1)-i = 5.1
j-(i+1) = 0.6
```

Return current results, since `j-i = 5.7` is closest.

Answer (score 0):

In this code fragment the `min` and `max` are indexes into the array:

```
int min=-1; 
int max=-1;
float mindiff = FLT_MAX;
for(int i=0; i < arraylength; ++i) {
    for(int j=i+1; j < arrayLength; ++j) {
        float diff = abs((max(values[i],values[j]) - min(values[i],values[j])) - difference);
        if (diff < mindiff) {
            if (values[i] < values[j]) {
               min = i;
               max = j;
           }
           else {
               min = j;
               max = i;
           }
           mindiff = diff;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not helping him by giving a full implementation, since this is homework.