# Find a value within a multidimensional array that is closest to a given value in Embedded C

Tags: c, arrays, embedded

I am developing an embedded colour sensing application with a microcontroller and a colour sensor using the C programming language.

At the moment, I have an array with calibration values that looks something like this
(Each row is a calibration for a different thing)

```
unsigned long calibrationValues[6][6]

value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6    
value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6
value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6
value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6
value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6
value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6
```

and another array

```
unsigned long scannedValue[6]
```

that holds six values that have been scanned for analysis against the calibration values

I know how I would check to see if the value exists within the array, but that is way too specific for what I would like to do as the value being scanned in for analysis could differ slightly to the exact calibrated value

**So, my question is:** How would I find the index of the result in the calibrationValues row that is the *closest* to the scannedValue value?

### Example

(values used below are just for example)

```
calibrationValues[6][6]

0 - 100 250 325 650 700 830
1 - 5   12  15  35  50  90
2 - ...
...

scannedValue[6]
0 - 350
1 - 80
2 - ...
...
```

scannedValue[0] is closest to calibrationValues[0][2]
scannedValue[1] is closest to calibrationValues[1][5]
...
etc

I have looked at other questions, in particular [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233951/how-to-find-which-value-is-closest-to-a-number-in-c) question but not sure how to adapt to a multidimensional array

Comment: What specifically don't you understan. Pass through each element of the multidimensional array, calculate  (abs(val-CONST)) and find the smallest one. That's your number.

Comment: Is the result meant to be a row of six elements?  I.e. one of the six rows in calibrationValues that most closely matches the input array?

Comment: @jimmcnamara the result would be an array of indexes of the closest values in the calibrationValues array. Each element in the scannedValue is only compared to one row in the calibrationValues array (so each value in that row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is as straight forward as it sounds:

```
int i, j;
int results[6];
int minDiff, diff;

for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    results[i] = 0; 
    minDiff = abs(scannedValue[i] - calibrationValues[i][0]);

    for (j = 1; j < 6; ++j)
    {
        diff = abs(scannedValue[i] - calibrationValues[i][j]);
        if (diff < minDiff)
        {
            minDiff = diff;
            results[i] = j;
        }
    }
}
```

The `results[]` array will contain the closest index from 0 to 5.

Comment: This does exactly what I have been trying to do, thank you very much for your prompt assistance